# How to get the pid when the program started by nohup?

Tags: linux, bash

My program of store_plus.py started by:

```
WORK_DIR=/usr/local/gdnsplus_reducecname
SPOOL_DIR=$WORK_DIR/var/spool
STORE_PLUS_SERVER="$WORK_DIR/bin/store_plus.py"
/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/python $STORE_PLUS_SERVER  1>$SPOOL_DIR/store_plus_nohup.out 2>&1 &
```

Now,I want to get the pid of store_plus.py. I try a way :

```
store_plus_prog="store_plus"
STORE_PID=`ps aux | grep $store_plus_prog | grep python | awk '{print $2}'`
```

As you see, this way is complex and used some pipelines. 
So, I want to use commands of **pidof**  and **pgrep**.

```
pidof store_plus.py
```

or

```
pgrep store_plus.py
```

But they can't work. Please give me some advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you read `$!`? It's a bash variable that stores the PID of the last process you created...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will achieve what you want.

```
pgrep -f store_plus.py
```

Per the man page:

-f: The pattern is normally only matched against the process name. When -f is set, the full command line is used.